# How to type the PublicKeyCredential in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, webauthn

I'm using the WebAuthN API and I want to use the `PublicKeyCredential` to detect an authenticator. But my TypeScript doesn't know this name and keeps telling me `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PublicKeyCredential'.`.

I did import the "@types/webappsec-credential-management" to have the right types. But my TypeScript doesn't want to compile for the same reasons.

Do you know how to add this to my `tsconfig.json` or another solution to use it correctly with TypeScript ?

Answer (score 5):

First you need to install the type.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/webappsec-credential-management
```

Then you need to add the type to your tsconfig.json file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [ "@types/webappsec-credential-management" ]
  }
}
```